# Activate Gmail Message or Open new Gmail Message Window with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, autohotkey

I'm trying to toggle to my new gmail message box but if it doesn't exist i would like my script to open gmail and open a new email (Compose new message).
Here's my existing script (previously provided by user285594)

```
^+m::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinTitleC :="Compose Mail - "
IfWinExist, %WinTitleC%
{
    WinActivate
    return
}else{
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2 
    IfWinExist, Chrome
    WinActivate ;
    WinWait, Chrome ;
    sleep, 100 ;
    chrome := "- Google Chrome"
    found := "false"
    tabSearch := "gmail"                 
    curWinNum := 0
    WinGet, numOfChrome, Count, %chrome% ; Get the number of chrome windows
    WinActivateBottom, %chrome% ; Activate the least recent window
    WinWaitActive %chrome% ; Wait until the window is active
    ControlFocus, Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1 ; Set the focus to tab control ???
    while (curWinNum < numOfChrome and found = "false") { 
        WinGetTitle, firstTabTitle, A ; The initial tab title
        title := firstTabTitle
        Loop {
            if(InStr(title, tabSearch)>0){
                found := "true"
                break
            }
            Send {Ctrl down}{Tab}{Ctrl up}
            Sleep, 50
            WinGetTitle, title, A  ;get active window title
            if(title = firstTabTitle){
                break
            }
        }
        WinActivateBottom, %chrome%
        curWinNum := curWinNum + 1
    }
    ControlSend, , {Shift Down}c{Shift Up}, Google Chrome
    winmove, Compose,, 1750, 303, 1725, 935 ; moving the window to my preferred position
    if(found = "false"){
        run C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ogbl#inbox
        WinWait, Inbox
        ControlSend, , {Shift Down}c , Google Chrome
        winmove, Compose,, 1750, 303, 1725, 935; moving the window to my preferred position
    }
}
return
```

It works when I have chrome open regardless of which tab I'm in. It does not work and seems to pause if chrome is minimized. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake lies on this line:

```
WinGetTitle, firstTabTitle, A ; The initial tab title
```

Here is a solution proposal:

```
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
ComposeTitle = Compose Mail - 
    
If WinExist(ComposeTitle . " ahk_exe chrome.exe") {
    WinActivate
    return
}

; Loop on all Chrome Windows    
WinGet, id, List,ahk_exe Chrome.exe
found := False
tabSearch = Gmail
Loop, %id%
{
    hWnd := id%A_Index%
    WinActivate, ahk_id %hWnd%
    ; Loop  on all Tabs in Chrome Window
    WinGetTitle, firstTabTitle, A
    title := firstTabTitle
    Loop {
        if (InStr(title, tabSearch)>0){
            found = True
            break
        }
        Send ^{Tab} ; switch to next tab
        Sleep, 50
        WinGetTitle, title, A  ;get active window title
        if (title = firstTabTitle){
            break
        }

    } ; end Loop Tabs
    if (found)
        break
} ; end loop Chrome windows

If !(found) {
    Run run C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#inbox"
    WinWait, Inbox ahk_exe Chrome.exe
} 

SendInput +c ; Shift+C
;WinWait %ComposeTitle%
;winmove, A,, 1750, 303, 1725, 935; moving the window to my preferred position
return
```

You can download the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tdalon/a6accc91b6ee197f9104efa9e285e396).

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this! For some reason, chrome still needs to be open (not necessarily active) but definitely not minimized for it to work as intended. But you definitely solved an issue for me. I'll just keep the window open at all times and not minimize. Many thanks!